# Swift horizontal UICollectionView with dynamic cell height

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, size, height

I have a horizontal collectionview with basic size is frame.width and 330 height. What i did:

1) Placed a collectionview and set constraints:
leading - 0, trailing - 0, top - 0, height - 330

2) Then set cell size to frame.width and height 330

3) But sometimes my cell has more content so i want to expand cell to 370

I tried, to create an outlet for collectionview constraint and change it on cellForItem method but seems like this is not the right way. 
Collection view placed in ScrollView if it matters[image]

Comment: You have to use flowLayout.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method name `estimateFrameForText` and this method will return a height value that will fit your string!

```
private func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    //we make the height arbitrarily large so we don't undershoot height in calculation
    let height: CGFloat = 320

    let size = CGSize(width: yourDesiredWidth, height: height)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightLight)]

    return NSString(string: text).boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
}
```

You have to use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement `sizeForItemAt` like the following. [make sure your class extend `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`]

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let sectionInset = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInset

         var referenceWidth: CGFloat = collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width

         var referenceHeight: CGFloat = 320

       //we are just measuring height so we add padding constant to give the label some room to breathe! 
       var padding: CGFloat = <someArbitraryPaddingValue>

       //estimate each cell's height
       if let text = array?[indexPath.item].text {
           referenceHeight= estimateFrameForText(text).height + padding
       }

        return CGSize(width: referenceWidth, height: referenceHeight)
    }
```

Comment: I've got: The item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

I've just create a tested project with 2 elements array to test it:

        var referenceHeight: CGFloat = 266
        if indexPath.item == 1 {
            referenceHeight = 300
        }
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: referenceHeight)

Comment: Okay, now i set the height constraint of collectionview also to 300 and it works as i wanted, but i still have an error above in log. What's wrong?

Comment: what is in your log. please add it to your question.